# Unterschied zwischen "es geht irgendwie" und "es ergeht irgendwie"

Tags: word-choice, difference, style

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen „gehen“ und „ergehen“ in den folgenden Beispielen? Ist „gehen“ in diesem Fall nur der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck für „ergehen“? Wenn nein, wann benutzt man ein Wort und wann das andere?

> Nie ging es mir besser als heute.
>
> Ihr ist es vor zehn Jahren noch nicht so gut gegangen.
>
> Bei der Prüfung ist alles gut gegangen.

---

> Bei seinen Eltern ist es ihm gut ergangen.
>
> Wenn du weiter so frech bist, wird es dir noch schlecht ergehen.
>
> Es ist ihr nicht schlecht ergangen.

Comment: Wieso, wenn die Begriffe verglichen werden sollen, änderst Du auch den sonstigen Satzgehalt? Was soll man so vergleichen können?

Answer (score 8):

> Ist “gehen” in diesem Fall nur der umgangsprächliche Ausdruck für “ergehen”?"

Nein.

`ergehen` bezieht sich darauf was einem Lebewesen über einen gewissen Zeitraum widerfährt, was es (alles) erlebt (hat).

```
Mir geht es gut.
Mir ist es [in den letzten drei Monaten] gut ergangen.
```

Aber nicht:

```
Die Prüfung geht gut.
Die Prüfung ist gut ergangen.
```

Der zweite Satz ist falsch.

In einer Frage kann man `ergangen` auch verwenden. Die Gegenwartsform von `gehen` hätte als Frage jedoch eine ganz andere Bedeutung, sie bezieht sich auf das aktuelle Befinden.

```
Wie ist es Dir ergangen? - Gut. | [Ausführliche Antwort]
Wie geht es Dir? - Mir geht es gerade gut.
```

(Mit `[Ausführliche Antwort]` meine ich, dass der Fragersteller üblicherweise eine detaillierte, umfangreiche Antwort erwartet.)

Ich kann mich an keine Kombination von `ergehen` mit Objekten erinnern.
Der Satz

```
Dem Haus ist es über die Jahre gut ergangen.
```

klingt komisch. Für Objekte würde ich eher folgendes sagen:

```
Das Haus hat sich gut gehalten.
```

(Gegenüber einem Menschen ist der Ausdruck `sich [gut] halten` hingegen eher unhöflich. ;)

Ein ähnliches Wort zu `ergangen` ist `widerfahren`:

```
Was ist Dir widerfahren?
```

Es ist aber kein Synonym, denn es bezieht sich auf einen konkreten Vorgang oder Vorfall.

```
- Ihm widerfuhr schreckliches.
- Heute ist ihr nur Unglück widerfahren: erst hat sie sich den Kopf gestoßen, dann ist sie hingefallen und am Abend hat sie sich in den Finger geschnitten.
  Kurz: in den letzten Stunden erging es ihr nicht gut.
```

:)

*English descriptions on demand*

Answer (score 2):

"Es geht mir gut" ist eine Aussage über den aktuellen Zustand.
"Es ergeht mir gut" ist eine Aussage über einen bestimmten, nicht näher definierten, Zeitraum.

Comment: Bitte keine Grüße verwenden - SE-weit nicht! "Bestimmten, nicht näher definierten" scheint mir ein Widerspruch in sich. Ist der Zeitraum bestimmt oder unbestimmt, definiert oder nicht? Wozu überhaupt drüber räsonnieren, wenn man nix weiß? Ebenso ist "aktueller IST-Zustand" 3x das gleiche. "Zustand" würde es schon sagen. In der Kürze liegt die Würze.

Answer (score 2):

Die Bedeutungen überschneiden sich zwar etwas.
*"Es ging ihm schlecht"* ist aber im wesentlichen eine
Aussage darüber, wie sich jemand *gefühlt* hat: er war
krank oder hatte Geldsorgen oder Liebeskummer.
*"Es ging ihm gut"* bedeutet entsprechend, dass derjenige
gesund und frei von Sorgen war.

*"Es erging ihm schlecht"* ist dagegen eine Aussage darüber,
dass jemandem etwas Schlechtes *zugestoßen* ist:
er verlor seine Stelle, hatte einen Unfall oder wurde Opfer
eines Verbrechens.
*"Es erging ihm gut"*
bedeutet entsprechend, dass demjenigen etwas Gutes *passiert* ist:
er wurde befördert, machte ein Vermögen an der Börse
und heiratete seine große Liebe.

Daneben gibt es einen Unterschied im Sprachniveau:
*"es geht jemandem gut/schlecht"* ist neutrales
Sprachniveau, *"es ergeht jemandem gut/schlecht"* eher gehobenes.