# Unterschied zwischen "gehen" und "ergehen"

Tags: meaning

Ich habe schon einen Artikel gelesen, in dem dieselbe Frage gestellt wurde, aber ich hätte gerne eine Klärung, denn ich darf noch nicht Kommentare schreiben.

Ist es richtig, zu sagen, dass "gehen" benutzt wird, um die aktuelle Situation zu beschreiben, aber "ergehen" die Situation über einen bestimmten Zeitraum?

Z.B.

- Es geht mir schlecht.
- Es ging mir gestern schlecht.
- Es ging mir vor 2 Jahren schlecht.

aber

- Es ist mir in letzter Zeit schlecht ergangen.
- Es wird mir hoffentlich über die nächsten 6 Wochen gut ergehen.

Comment: [Diese Frage?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13514/unterschied-zwischen-es-geht-irgendwie-und-es-ergeht-irgendwie)

Comment: @Stephie Ja, wahrscheinlich. Das Problem ist, dass die Antwort von Exportforce darauf ziemlicher Unsinn ist, und Rixterz dadurch in die Irre geführt wurde. Die Antwort von try-catch-finally ist besser, trifft es aber m.E. auch nicht ganz.

Comment: @Stephie Die Antwort sollte dann auf die ältere Frage gegeben werden. Ich überlege noch, wie ich es ausdrücken soll.

Comment: @Stephie Erledigt.